# Using CSS, how to "tightly" align "A" to the bottom/end of "B" where "B" has unknown width and text wrapping

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table, alignment

I have a "sortable" table where the header of the currently sorted column displays an icon:

[image]

The sort icon is to be displayed at the *end* of the text (i.e., we are supporting LTR/RTL). I'm currently using `display:flex`. However, if the table width shrinks and the column header text begins to wrap, I run into ambiguous states where it's not clear which column is sorted:

[image]

Instead I would like to meet the following requirements:

1. The icon is always be "tightly" aligned with the "end" *of the longest line of text* (even if the wrapping cell/button is wider).
2. The icon should also be bottom-aligned with the last row of text.
3. The icon should never wrap onto a line of its own.
4. The button must be present and should span the full width of the cell. (It's internal styling and markup can change as needed.)
5. CSS and HTML only if at all possible.
6. It cannot rely on known/set column widths or header text.

For example:

[image]

I've been experimenting with a bunch of different combinations of `display: inline/inline-block/flex/grid`, `position`, `::before/::after`, and even `float` (!) but can't get the desired behavior. Here is my current code demonstrating the problem:

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.thead {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d0d3d3;
}

.thead .tr {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.button {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: start;
  font-family: Arial, "noto sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.sort {
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead">
    <tr class="tr">
      <th class="th">
        <button class="button">
          Age
          <span class="sort"></span>
         </button>
      </th>
      <th class="th">
        <button class="button">
          Favorite Food
          <span class="sort"></span>
        </button>
      </th>
      <th class="th" aria-sort="ascending">
        <button class="button">
          Favorite Color
          <span class="sort">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="presentation" style="width: 1.25rem; height: 1.25rem;"> <path d="M11.4709 4.2136C11.7638 3.92071 12.2386 3.92071 12.5315 4.2136L17.1277 8.8098C17.4206 9.10269 17.4206 9.57756 17.1277 9.87046C16.8348 10.1633 16.3599 10.1633 16.0671 9.87046L12.7512 6.55459V19.25C12.7512 19.6642 12.4154 20 12.0012 20C11.587 20 11.2512 19.6642 11.2512 19.25V6.55459L7.93533 9.87046C7.64244 10.1633 7.16756 10.1633 6.87467 9.87046C6.58178 9.57756 6.58178 9.10269 6.87467 8.8098L11.4709 4.2136Z"> </path></svg>
          </span>
        </button>
      </th>
      <th class="th">
        <button class="button">
          Likes Neil Diamond?
          <span class="sort"></span>
        </button>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this UI? This probably has little to do with the table or button stuff. Really I need `Thing A` "tightly" bottom/end aligned to `Thing B` (of a flexible width and which can have wrapped text) but `Thing A` can't wrap onto a line of its own.

I've tried messing with the `flex` values but any combination either makes the text wrap prematurely or not soon enough.

Comment: I tried to fix your issue with your current css and html however the button and the span element combined where a headache so I decided to use font-awesome with css and html here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/8qwocyrs/169/) hope it helps

Comment: @stanchacon thanks for taking a look. I should have mentioned, but I won't have the luxury of setting column widths or knowing what the header text will be ahead of time. I added #6 to the requirements.

Comment: @stanchacon ...and I could go for a ribeye right about now :)

Comment: @robertwbradford Is this already addressed? Or you're still looking for a solution?

Comment: @MohammedFurqanRahamathM, this has not been answered yet. Still looking...

Comment: @robertwbradford Is there a reason why you are not considering `flex-direction:row-reverse` on the `.button` blocks inside the table headers`th`?

Answer (score 1):

Think you need JS for this. Here's an answer that should meet all conditions except 5.

```js
const debounce = fn => {
  let frame;

  return (...params) => {
    if (frame) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(frame);
    }
    frame = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      fn(...params);
    });
  };
};

const text = [...document.querySelectorAll(".text")];
const iconWidth = "1.25rem";

const positionIcon = () => {
  if (!text) return;
  
  text.forEach(t => {
    const width = t.getBoundingClientRect().width;

    const icon = t.nextElementSibling;
    if (!icon) return;
    
    icon.style.left = `calc(${width}px + ${iconWidth})`;
  });
};

positionIcon();
window.addEventListener("resize", debounce(positionIcon));
```

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.thead {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d0d3d3;
}

.thead .tr {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.button {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: start;
  font-family: Arial, "noto sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.4;
  position: relative;
}

.sort {
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 100%; /* no js fallback */
}

.sort svg {
  height: 1.25rem;
  width: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
   <svg id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation"> <path d="M11.4709 4.2136C11.7638 3.92071 12.2386 3.92071 12.5315 4.2136L17.1277 8.8098C17.4206 9.10269 17.4206 9.57756 17.1277 9.87046C16.8348 10.1633 16.3599 10.1633 16.0671 9.87046L12.7512 6.55459V19.25C12.7512 19.6642 12.4154 20 12.0012 20C11.587 20 11.2512 19.6642 11.2512 19.25V6.55459L7.93533 9.87046C7.64244 10.1633 7.16756 10.1633 6.87467 9.87046C6.58178 9.57756 6.58178 9.10269 6.87467 8.8098L11.4709 4.2136Z"> </path></svg>
</svg>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead">
    <tr class="tr">
      <th class="th">
        <button class="button">
          <span class="text">Age</span>
          <span class="sort">
            <svg>
              <use xlink:href="#arrow">
            </svg>
          </span>
         </button>
      </th>
      <th class="th">
        <button class="button">
          <span class="text">Favourite Food</span>
          <span class="sort">
          <svg>
              <use xlink:href="#arrow">
            </svg>
          </span>
        </button>
      </th>
      <th class="th" aria-sort="ascending">
        <button class="button">
          <span class="text">Favorite Color</span>
          <span class="sort">
            <svg>
              <use xlink:href="#arrow">
            </svg>
          </span>
        </button>
      </th>
      <th class="th">
        <button class="button">
          <span class="text">Likes Neil Diamond?</span>
          <span class="sort">
            <svg>
              <use xlink:href="#arrow">
            </svg>
          </span>
        </button>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no issue here at all except visual ambiguity. Here are my observations.

- The items in-fact are tightly bound. By default any element would follow another unless specified otherwise.
- Why there is a spacing? There are two variations of these

  - **First: If the text is not inside any wrapping element** (the state in which it is in right now). 
          In this scenario, since there is no width mentioned explicitly, for both text as well as span, there is automatic assignment of width and the text is trying to all the width except the 1.25rem width the span element is taking. And according to w3c documentation, the rules exist only to identify the breakpoints on a given string and not spacing, because text justification is an entirely different problem. Please refer [this problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/word-wrap-problem-dp-19/) to understand how it is done, its a standard Dynamic programming question studied in college. So of course spacing will exist while doing justification and please remember the available width, which the browser is not going to collapse.
  - **Second: If the text is inside a wrapping element**, could be span, p, div etc. In this case also, the auto assignment of width happens as no width is explicitly specified. And in this case, you can actually see in inspect element that the element tries to occupy all the space except the 1.25rem width of the sort icon.

So **tight** bounding, does exist, its just that dynamic spacing is causing the visual ambiguity.

Now coming to the solution, the closest solution that I could come up with **without JavaScript intervention**, although not perfect, is,

- Wrap the text inside an element, maybe a span
- Limit the width of this text by giving a max-width:

  ```
  button.button > span {
      max-width: 60%; // I saw this to be decent enough
      text-align: center; // This is to offset the visual effect of spacing
  }
  ```

**Note:** The `text-align: center` is only to reduce the effect of missing space, unless you've strict requirement not to go with this.

Please let me know if this addresses your question.

This is how the effect would be:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For this we do have a requirement for it to be at the end.

Comment: @robertwbradford I have changed my answer explaining the possible issue you're facing and proposed a solution. Please let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost good and missing the (3) which is a bit trick. An idea is to make the icon element having a width equal to `0` and disable any whitespace between the text and the sort icon. For this I use an extra wrapper for the text and removed the use of flexbox.

You will have some overflow but it's not an issue since you are applying padding. You can also increase the `padding-right` if you want

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.thead {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d0d3d3;
}

.thead .tr {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.button {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: start;
  font-family: Arial, "noto sans", sans-serif;
  font-size:0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
.button > span {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
.sort {
  width: 0;
  height: 1.25rem;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead">
    <tr class="tr">
      <th class="th">
        <button class="button">
          <span>Age</span>
          <span class="sort"></span>
         </button>
      </th>
      <th class="th">
        <button class="button">
          <span>Favorite Food</span>
          <span class="sort"></span>
        </button>
      </th>
      <th class="th" aria-sort="ascending">
        <button class="button">
          <span>Favorite Color</span>
          <span class="sort">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="presentation" style="width: 1.25rem; height: 1.25rem;"> <path d="M11.4709 4.2136C11.7638 3.92071 12.2386 3.92071 12.5315 4.2136L17.1277 8.8098C17.4206 9.10269 17.4206 9.57756 17.1277 9.87046C16.8348 10.1633 16.3599 10.1633 16.0671 9.87046L12.7512 6.55459V19.25C12.7512 19.6642 12.4154 20 12.0012 20C11.587 20 11.2512 19.6642 11.2512 19.25V6.55459L7.93533 9.87046C7.64244 10.1633 7.16756 10.1633 6.87467 9.87046C6.58178 9.57756 6.58178 9.10269 6.87467 8.8098L11.4709 4.2136Z"> </path></svg>
          </span>
        </button>
      </th>
      <th class="th">
        <button class="button">
          <span>Likes Neil Diamond?</span>
          <span class="sort"></span>
        </button>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Some good points, but I'm seeing it not meet "requirement 1" where the arrow would need to be aligned with end of the longest row of text. In the case of "Favorite Color," when "Color" wraps to the second line, the icon should horizontally align with the end of "Favorite" as shown in the the last screenshot.

Comment: @robertwbradford ah didn't understand it that way .. I thought it should be tight with the last one. I think you are out of luck for this requirement ...

Answer (score 0):

if your thead title are not dynamic then i have very easy fix.

for this you will have to put the last word of title and svg icon in span together

eg:-html

```
<button>
 Long 

<span> title 
 <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="presentation" style="width: 1.25rem; height: 1.25rem;"> <path d="M11.4709 4.2136C11.7638 3.92071 12.2386 3.92071 12.5315 4.2136L17.1277 8.8098C17.4206 9.10269 17.4206 9.57756 17.1277 9.87046C16.8348 10.1633 16.3599 10.1633 16.0671 9.87046L12.7512 6.55459V19.25C12.7512 19.6642 12.4154 20 12.0012 20C11.587 20 11.2512 19.6642 11.2512 19.25V6.55459L7.93533 9.87046C7.64244 10.1633 7.16756 10.1633 6.87467 9.87046C6.58178 9.57756 6.58178 9.10269 6.87467 8.8098L11.4709 4.2136Z"> </path></svg>
</span>
</button>
```

remove display:flex from .button class
and give style display:inline-block to the added span

due to span being inline-block the svg icon will never be in seperate line. there will at least be one word in front of it

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am building this as a component, so the title text will be dynamic :(

Comment: You can use Js to to put last word in span. It should not that hard

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this :

```css
<style>

.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.thead {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d0d3d3;
}

.thead .tr {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}


.button {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: start;
  font-family: Arial, "noto sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
    
 /* display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;*/
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.4;
  float: left;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:502px)
{.button {
    width: calc(192px - 89px);
  }
  .button.food {
    width: calc(214px - 89px);
}
}

.sort {
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  position: relative;
}
.sort svg {
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead">
    <tr class="tr">
      <th class="th">
        <button class="button">
          Age
          <span class="sort"></span>
         </button>
      </th>
      <th class="th">
        <button class="button food">
          Favorite Food
          <span class="sort"></span>
        </button>
      </th>
      <th class="th" aria-sort="ascending">
        <button class="button">
          Favorite Color
          <span class="sort">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="presentation" style="width: 1.25rem; height: 1.25rem;"> <path d="M11.4709 4.2136C11.7638 3.92071 12.2386 3.92071 12.5315 4.2136L17.1277 8.8098C17.4206 9.10269 17.4206 9.57756 17.1277 9.87046C16.8348 10.1633 16.3599 10.1633 16.0671 9.87046L12.7512 6.55459V19.25C12.7512 19.6642 12.4154 20 12.0012 20C11.587 20 11.2512 19.6642 11.2512 19.25V6.55459L7.93533 9.87046C7.64244 10.1633 7.16756 10.1633 6.87467 9.87046C6.58178 9.57756 6.58178 9.10269 6.87467 8.8098L11.4709 4.2136Z"> </path></svg>
          </span>
        </button>
      </th>
      <th class="th">
        <button class="button">
          Likes Neil Diamond?
          <span class="sort"></span>
        </button>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Hope this answer will helpful to you.I did not make css for mobile view!